# How to fix api keys stored in local env getting lost while deploying to firebase using Github actions?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, environment-variables, github-actions, cicd

Basically the question title says it all. While using Github actions for automatic deployment of my react application, the api keys for firebase, which are stored in `.env.local` are getting lost on the way, meaning the deployed application isn't working at all, whilst if I deploy it manually, it works.

Does anyone know the solution for this? Thanks!

Edit : link to Github actions config file
https://github.com/bogdiusf/gymeasure-production/blob/master/.github/workflows/main.yml

Edit 2 : Fixed the problem. Full solution found in `main.yml`

```
- name: Create env file
        run: |
          touch .env.local
          echo REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY=${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY }} >> .env.local
          echo REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN=${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN }} >> .env.local
          echo REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL=${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL }} >> .env.local
          echo REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID }} >> .env.local
          echo REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET=${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET }} >> .env.local
          echo REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID=${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID }} >> .env.local
          echo REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID=${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID }} >> .env.local
```

I added this before running `npm run build`

Comment: Can you show your Git Actions config?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Yes sir. Here's a link to the `.yml` file or even the whole repository if needed.
https://github.com/bogdiusf/gymeasure-production/blob/master/.github/workflows/main.yml